# Why are time savings minimal when reading a large CSV in parallel?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm testing the possibility of reading a large CSV file simultaneously with different processes using pandas and the Python multiprocessing module.

There are some time savings, but they're pretty minimal. At first I thought maybe it had to do with how fast data can be read from a hard drive, but I don't think that's why because reading a large text file or a large Python pickle file is much faster.

Please see code below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time
from datetime import datetime
import multiprocessing as mp
from util import memchk
import re


FILE_LENGTH = 1000000
INFILE = 'rtest.1mX80.csv'



def single():
    df = pd.read_csv(INFILE)
    return df

def now():
    currentTime = datetime.now()
    formattedTime = f"{currentTime.hour}:{currentTime.minute:02}:{currentTime.second:02}.{currentTime.microsecond/1000:03.0f}"
    return formattedTime

def process_name():
    fullName = f"{mp.current_process()}"
    name = re.search(r'PoolWorker-\d', fullName).group()
    return name

def read_chunk(skiprows, nrows):
    print(f'({now()} | {process_name()}) Starting to read a chunk...')
    start = time.perf_counter()
    df = pd.read_csv(INFILE, skiprows=skiprows, nrows=nrows)
    end = time.perf_counter()
    print(f"({now()} | {process_name()}) Read the chunk in {end-start:.2f} seconds!")
    return df

def parallel():
    nrows = int(FILE_LENGTH/4)
    skiprows = [i * nrows for i in range(4)]
    starmapArgs = zip(skiprows, [nrows] * 4)
    with mp.Pool(4) as pool:
        dfs = pool.starmap(read_chunk, starmapArgs)
        df = pd.concat(dfs, sort=False)
    return df

def gen_df(nrows, ncols):
    colnames = [f"col{i}" for i in range(1, ncols+1)]
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(nrows, ncols), columns=colnames)
    return df


if __name__ == "__main__":
    gen_df(FILE_LENGTH, 80).to_csv('rtest.1mX80.csv', index=False)

    start = time.perf_counter()
    df1 = single()
    end = time.perf_counter()
    print(f"Finished reading file (singleprocessing) in {end-start:.2f} seconds.")

    start = time.perf_counter()
    df2 = parallel()
    end = time.perf_counter()
    print(f"Finished reading file (multiprocessing) in {end-start:.2f} seconds.")
```

What is the reason why multiprocessing is only marginally faster when reading large files in pandas? Is it some kind of hardware limitation, or is it more closely related to the pandas implementation of `read_csv`?

Comment: A CSV is nothing more than a text file. The problem is the code. Instead of splitting the file in 4 and having each process read a chunk, all of them read the same file but some of them discard the rows they read. This means that the 4th process will read the *entire* file but only process the last quarter of it.

Comment: In any case using multiple processes will never *read* the file any faster precisely because there's only one disk that can serve that file. Using multiple processes is useful when a) there are a lot of files to process or b) *processing* costs much more than reading the file. Parsing a CSV isn't expensive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case the problem has two parts;

- Reading the data from disk.
- Converting the rows to Pandas.

Normally speaking reading from disk is *extremely slow*.

The first possible solution to make that faster is to use an SSD. :-)

If that is not practical, another solution is to use `mmap`. Using `mmap` to read a file can speed things up significantly. When you start reading from an `mmap`-ed file, the OS should notice that and map the next page(s) into memory before you get there.

And this can be combined with `multiprocessing.Pool`.
If you create the `mmap` *before* creating the `Pool` and a list of *n* offsets for the *n* workers, all the worker processes *should* have access to that. The workers then only have to start reading from a their offset to the next.

**Edit**: I would do reading the file with `multiprocessing` as follows.

- Determine the file size (e.g. `os.stat`)
- Open the file, `seek` to 1/4 of the file.
- Read say 4 kB, find the first newline in there. Save the total offset of that newline.
- Do the same for 1/2 of the file and 3/4 of the file.

Using this, create a list of 4 (start, end) file offset pairs.
Give that list to `Pool.map()`. The worker should then read the data between the offsets, split it into lines and parse the CSV.

That would divide the CSV conversion without reading the whole file multiple times.

Comment: Thanks, but it seems that using `mmap` had only a marginal impact. Perhaps part of the issue is that I already have a SSD. I created an `mmap` object outside of the `Pool` and yet what I notice is that the first chunk is read in 12 seconds, the second chunk in 14 seconds, the third chunk in 17 seconds, and the fourth chunk in 18 seconds. I think this is only a marginal improvement over using a regular file. Reading the whole file into a Pandas DataFrame takes 26 seconds.

Comment: Using `mmap` is an *alternative* for an SSD. If you already have an SSD, there is probably not much more performance to be had.

Comment: I think part of the issue is that, as Panagiotis said above, when I call `pd.read_csv(filepath, skiprows=500000, nrows=250000)` it has to read a good chunk of the data before getting to the rows that it actually needs to parse into a DataFrame. I might look into the source code for `pd.read_csv` and see if I can modify it so that it takes a list of lines. That way, I only have to read the file into memory once, and then I'll pass a list of 250000 lines into each of the four processes (assuming that the original file has 1 million rows).

Comment: @N4v I think there is a good way to chop up the file reading and CSV conversion for `multiprocessing.Pool`. See **edit** in the answer.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that and it works. Each process completes in the same amount of time. 

The total performance improvement ends up being only around 20-30% though, probably due to the limitation of how fast one can read data from a hard drive.

Comment: @N4v Another thought; using a RAM disk is probably faster than an SSD...